# Swagger enum values not getting displayed in drop down?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

This is my controller method where the enum is accepted

```
@GetMapping("/{sortBy}/{page}/{size}")
    public ResponseDto<ReviewsResponseDto, Void> searchAllReviews(
            @PathVariable(value = "sortBy") ReviewsSortBy sortBy,
            @PathVariable Integer page, @PathVariable Integer size)
```

This is my enum ReviewsSortBy

```
@Getter
@ToString
public enum ReviewsSortBy {
      DEFAULT,
      FEATURED,
      RECENT;
}
```

Now the problem is that swagger doesnt display the possible values of enum in dropdown, instead it just displays "ReviewsSortBy()" as the only selectable value in the dropdown list of the same.

NOTE : Swagger version 2.9.2

Here is the screenshot for the same.
[image: swagger dropdown issue with enums]

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using springboot w/ springfox. I had a similar issue but not identical issue. Explicitly specifying an allowable content-type using the `consumes` property of Spring's request mapping annotations results in enum dropdown fields in Swagger becoming text boxes.

### Text Inputs

```java
  @PostMapping(value = "/items/{uuid}/images",
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
      consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
  @PreAuthorize(Scopes.PUBLISH)
  public ImageMetadataDTO upload(@PathVariable @Uuid String 
      @RequestParam(value = "graphicType") GraphicType
```

### Enum Dropdowns

```java
  @PostMapping(value = "/items/{uuid}/images",
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  @PreAuthorize(Scopes.PUBLISH)
  public ImageMetadataDTO upload(@PathVariable @Uuid String 
      @RequestParam(value = "graphicType") GraphicType
```

Comment: explicitly mentioning if it shows, in 1st part of code it is explicitly mentioned & heading of that is Text Inputs