# Can't display values in select Swagger menu

Tags: java, spring, swagger

How can I make a menu for selecting a value of type int (1,2,3 ..) displayed in Swagger? I created an enum class but no values are displayed?

`someMethod( @RequestParam Integer status)`

[image]

Comment: Does this help/answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075653/swagger-enum-values-not-getting-displayed-in-drop-down

Answer (score 0):

You can use allowableValues with @ApiParam annotation

```
someMethod( @ApiParam(allowableValues = "START,STOP", required = true) @RequestParam Integer status)
```

Swagger doc link
http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html#allowableValues()

Comment: Thanks, also recently found this in baeldung. Thank you very much!